# Changing Row Colors in Visual Studio for a Report

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Don't know if this is possible (or it's really tedious to do it) but I was wondering if there is a way in Visual Studio to have a variety of different background colors and font colors for particular rows in a VS  report?

!(http://i60.tinypic.com/2ed09c3.png)

Here is just a sample report table I currently have that is generating a whole bunch of rows using a query.

In any case, right now it just has the colored title head and just rows of white background and black text.

What I would like to see in the output rows is the ability to - say - if the ChartID = 1 then all the background colors for that ChartID will be yellow with red text

And if I have a ChartID=2, some other colors will be selected, etc.

Is there anyway that I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156400(v=sql.90).aspx

This is actually exactly what I needed